# bundle install: Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL:...certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

In Windows, when upgrading to rails. 4.1.0.beta1, `bundle install` creates an error with gem minitest:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.r
    ubygems.org/gems/minitest-5.2.1.gem)
```

Similar error happened before and we usually got around by trying to install an older version. But this time minitest 5.2.0 has the same error. What's the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Comment: change `source 'https://rubygems.org'` to `source 'http://rubygems.org'` in your `Gemfile`

Comment: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/319  here is an issue report with details.

Answer (score 8):

@bjhaid needs to write his comment above here as an answer, as that's the answer.

"change source 'https://rubygems.org' to source 'http://rubygems.org' in your Gemfile"